# How to create pending migration sql server script using C# code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, migration

My requirement is in any case migration updations fails I need to send admin an email with sql script of all pending migartion.I am not getting how can I generate teh sql script of pending migration in C# code.

```
  var migrator = new DbMigrator(config);
  if (migrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any())
      {
           migrator.Update();
      }
```